# Can you select a custom element by the is: attribute?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a selector for a custom element, can you use the `is:` attribute ?

`querySelector(div[is:'custom-element'])` ?

```js
class CustomDiv extends HTMLDivElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}
customElements.define('custom-element', CustomDiv, {
  extends: 'div'
})

// const newElement = new CustomDiv()
// document.querySelector('body').append(newElement)
```

```css
div {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div is='custom-element'></div>
```

Comment: This question was turning into something else, so I posted another (custom elements missing the `is:` attribute) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77661617/custom-elements-created-with-the-new-keyword-or-createelement-dont-have-the-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
It's almost it.

Try this:

`let element = document.querySelector("div[is='custom-element']")`

Comment: That won't find ones that don't have the `is` attribute, like the one the OP's commented-out code adds.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'll post another question regarding the `is:` attribute, MDN says `The new element will be given an is attribute whose value is the custom element's tag name.` but it doens't

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's another question as OP mentioned., it really doesn't work.

Comment: @CaioHenrique - Yeah, my comment was before the OP decided to split off half the question into something else entirely (which made this one an obvious duplicate; the basics of attribute selectors are already well-covered here). In the original form of the question, just an attribute selector didn't do the job, *because* of the issue the OP mentioned about `is` not getting set.