# Custom elements created with the new keyword or createElement() don't have the is: attribute, why?

Tags: javascript

Creating a custom element using the `new` keyword from a class or using `createElement('div', {is: 'custom-element'})` doesn't have the `is:` attribute.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) on `createElement` says `The new element will be given an is attribute whose value is the custom element's tag name.`

But when inspecting them the `is:` attribute it is missing, is this a bug ?

```js
class CustomDiv extends HTMLDivElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}
customElements.define('custom-element', CustomDiv, {
  extends: 'div'
})

const newElement = new CustomDiv()
document.querySelector('body').append(newElement)

const anotherNewElement = document.createElement('div', {is: 'custom-element'})

document.querySelector('body').append(anotherNewElement)
```

```css
div {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Standard Administrator Response no. 1 - works for me (Edge Browser)

Comment: Another POV What do you want to do with an _is_ attribute?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Was looking for a way to `querySelector()` by the is attribute when I saw it was not there. 

Also, If Apple says it will never implement it,  is using customized built in elements quite unusual then ? Better off just extending `HTMLElement` ?

Comment: @FlashThunder - From the question: *"But when inspecting them the is: attribute it is missing."* That's true on Edge as well (for me), the elements don't have an `is` attribute. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: oh sorry, my bad... no `is` attribute, do you have any other questions? (haha I can always pretend to be AI in such a situation xD)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web Components : extending native elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619025/web-components-extending-native-elements)

Comment: See link to duplicate answer. All this _does_ make ``is`` the safest custom attribute you can use **yourself**, because the WHATWG will not use it for anything else

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman It does, this clarified it even further https://stackoverflow.com/a/72090672/13040656 I get the diff between Customized Built-In Elements and Autonomous Elements and and now about what works on Safari and what doesn't. Though I think we can leave this question up too because it ask about the missing attribute specifically and why it does not behave like the docs say, and Mr. Crowder provided a nice answer.

Comment: The very simple answer is: Attributes change things and and ``is`` attribute would not change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Chromium browsers (Blink+V8 except on iOS) nor Firefox (Gecko+SpiderMonkey except on iOS) set the `is` attribute as described. (Safari [WebKit+JavaScriptCore] doesn't support customized built-in elements at all; [1](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=182671), [2](https://github.com/WebKit/standards-positions/issues/97). And since iOS is a walled garden where all browsers have to use WebKit+JavaScriptCore, there's no iOS support for this at all, even using Chromium or Firefox.)

You'd have to go digging through the HTML standard discussion archives, but I suspect MDN's information there is either outdated or cutting edge. :-) The specification says:

> Two distinct types of custom elements can be defined:
>
> - An autonomous custom element, which is defined with no `extends` option. These types of custom elements have a local name equal to their defined name.
> - A customized built-in element, which is defined with an `extends` option. These types of custom elements have a local name equal to the value passed in their `extends` option, and their defined name is used as the value of the `is` attribute, which therefore must be a valid custom element name.
>
> After a custom element is created, changing the value of the `is` attribute does not change the element's behavior, as it is saved on the element as its [`is` value](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element-is-value).

Note the phrasing, "is used as" as opposed to "is **set** as". (Not hyper-clear, but sadly a **lot** of the HTML spec isn't hyper-clear if you aren't on the standards board or an experienced browser implementer. Note: I am neither.)

The "`is` value" link says:

> Elements have an associated namespace, namespace prefix, local name, custom element state, custom element definition, `is` value. When an element is created, all of these values are initialized.

Given that the "`is` value" is at the same level of information as an element's local name, namespace, custom element state, etc. and adding to the list of fundamental information about an element is not something to be done lightly, I suspect that actually *setting* the attribute turned out not to be web-compatible and so they had to fall back to defining a new thing. That's speculation, though. It's equally possible that having `createElement` *set* the attribute value is a recent change and implementations just haven't caught up.

Either way, you can make it true of your own custom elements by setting it in the constructor:

```
class CustomDiv extends HTMLDivElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.setAttribute("is", "custom-element");
    }
}
```

```js
class CustomDiv extends HTMLDivElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.setAttribute("is", "custom-element");
    }
}
customElements.define("custom-element", CustomDiv, {extends: "div"});

let newElement = new CustomDiv();
newElement.textContent = "Created via constructor";
document.body.append(newElement);

newElement = document.createElement("div", {is: "custom-element"});
newElement.textContent = "Created via createElement";
document.body.append(newElement)

console.log(`Found via [is="custom-element"]:`);
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll("[is=custom-element]")) {
    console.log(`"${element.textContent}"`);
}
```

```html
<div>Not a custom-element</div>
<div is="custom-element">Defined in HTML</div>
```

If you **don't** want to do that, you can't use an attribute selector, and a tag selector won't work unless the tag was actually used directly to create the element. You could search for the base element and filter the list to only include those that are instances of your custom element:

```
const custom = [...document.querySelectorAll("div")]
    .filter((el) => el instanceof CustomDiv);
```

```js
class CustomDiv extends HTMLDivElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
customElements.define("custom-element", CustomDiv, {extends: "div"});

let newElement = new CustomDiv();
newElement.textContent = "Created via constructor";
document.body.append(newElement);

newElement = document.createElement("div", {is: "custom-element"});
newElement.textContent = "Created via createElement";
document.body.append(newElement)

console.log(`Found via [is="custom-element"]:`);
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll("[is=custom-element]")) {
    console.log(`"${element.textContent}"`);
}
console.log("NOTE: Not all of them were found by the above");

console.log(`Found via query for divs filtered by inheriting from CustomDiv:`);
for (const element of [...document.querySelectorAll("div")].filter((el) => el instanceof CustomDiv)) {
    console.log(`"${element.textContent}"`);
}
```

```html
<div>Not a custom-element</div>
<div is="custom-element">Defined in HTML</div>
```

Sadly neither will work in environments that don't support them (except the attribute selector on elements you explicitly define to have `is`).

Comment: Apple has always stated they will not implement _customized built in elements_

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - Yeah, I was just about to come back and edit in [these](https://github.com/WebKit/standards-positions/issues/97) [links](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=182671) about that. But the question is still valid for engines that *do* implement it.